# @arcgis/node is introduced in node

Tags: javascript

I need to introduce @ arcgis/node into the node but after introducing `error __dirname` not defined I have modified the source code, but to quote the following error:

[image]

Comment: Node ArcGIS (Deprecated). https://esri.github.io/node-arcgis/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.